# Events with backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Trying to set up a basic backbone.js example - can't get events to fire. What am I missing?

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/backbone/backbone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>

    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="helloworld">
        <button id="sayhello">
            Say Hello
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here is JS

```
(function($) {

HelloWorldView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el : '#helloworld',

    events: {'click #sayhello': 'onButtonClicked'},

    onButtonClicked: function()
    {
        console.log("buttonclicked");
    },

    render : function() {
        console.log("rendering");
        $(this.el).html("Hello world");
    }
});

var helloView = new HelloWorldView().render();})(jQuery);
```

Any idea why I can't get the events to fire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `render` method kills `#sayhello`:

```
render : function() {
    console.log("rendering");
    $(this.el).html("Hello world"); // #sayhello is now gone
}
```

So there is no `#sayhello` to click on and your event handler never gets called.

Perhaps your `render` is supposed to look more like this:

```
render: function() {
        console.log("rendering");
        $(this.el).find('button').html("Hello world");
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4empG/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out however, I still wasn't able to capture onButtonClicked event?

Comment: @Andrei: The demo (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4empG/) works so what are you doing differently? The only change I made in the demo is the new `render` as in my answer.

Comment: this is odd, when I paste my local code in JSFiddle it works; no such luck locally. The HTML is exactly the same as above...

Comment: I can log the initial console.log("rendering"); but can't change the button label...

Comment: That's because you're trying to change the DOM when the DOM isn't ready, you need to create and render your view from a `$(document).ready()` callback.

Answer (score 0):

actually you replace whole html with "Hello World"
    $(this.el).html("Hello World");
it's better, you just find the button and change html.
    this.$('#sayhello').html('Hello World');